# Bootstrap 3 with Typeahead - how get id from json?

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    ajax: { 
        url: './test.php',
        triggerLength: 1 
    }
});
```

test.php returns json:

```
[{"id":"13","name":"\u0410\u0420\u0425\u0418\u0412"},
{"id":"12","name":"\u041a\u043e\u043f\u0438\u0440\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0435\u0440"},
{"id":"11","name":"\u041f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0449\u043d\u0438\u043a \u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0434\u0436\u0435\u0440\u0430"}]
```

*Tell me please how me output in `console.log()` or in `alert()` element `id` from json when we select value typeahead?*

P.S.: *or only how get `id` from json ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
        ajax: { 
                url: './test.php',
                triggerLength: 1 
              },
    onSelect: function(item) {
        console.log(item); // return full object
        console.log(item.value); // return value - it your id
        return item;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign this to some variable, and then using index get element, and then its field ID:

```
var a = [{"id":"13","name":"\u0410\u0420\u0425\u0418\u0412"},    {"id":"12","name":"\u041a\u043e\u043f\u0438\u0440\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0435\u0440"},
{"id":"11","name":"\u041f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0449\u043d\u0438\u043a \u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0434\u0436\u0435\u0440\u0430"}]
```

And then you get:

```
a[0].id = 13
```

Comment: me need show on example `typeahead` (see question please)

Answer (score 0):

This is the common way to work with Typeahead (100% working code from a project I did):

```
var films = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: './test.php'
});

films.initialize();

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: films.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>{{value}} ({{year}}) <span class="label label-elegant">{{videoRes width height}}</span></p>')
    }
});
```

It uses Handlebars for templating and Bloodhound as suggestion engine
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md

Now, as you said, you need to make a `console.log` of your received data, here is the example code:

```
var films = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: './test.php'
});

films.initialize();

var autocomplete_template = Handlebars.compile('<p>{{value}} ({{year}}) <span class="label label-elegant">{{videoRes width height}}</span></p>');;

function suggestions_html(x){
    // Log function
    console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    return autocomplete_template(x);
}

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: films.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: suggestions_html
    }
});
```